# ¿Cómo manejo un selector dependiente al editar?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, selectores

Tengo un selector dependiente hecho con ajax,jquery y cakephp .

La relación es la siguiente Edificios tienen muchas unidades y las unidades pertenecen a un edificio , es bien simple.

El tema es que cuando quiero editar el registro el segundo selector no me carga la unidad guardada ni el ajax

Si selecciono otro edificio funciona bien , pero al ingresar muestra vacío a pesar de que tiene una unidad cargada ,como muestra la imagen(muestra que no cargó correctamente la unidad, está vacia) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El agregar funciona correctamente pero el editar no porque no encuentro la forma de enviarle al ajax la data guardada

Dejo el código completo

inputs:

```
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Edificio</label>
                <?= $this->Form->control('edificio_id', [
                    'empty' => 'Seleccione un edificio',
                    'class' => 'form-control', 
                    'label' => false, 
                    'required' => true,
                    'options' => $edificios, 
                    'id'=>'edificio_id'
                ]); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Unidad</label>
                <?= $this->Form->control('unidad_id', [
                    'class' => 'form-control', 
                    'label' => false, 
                    'required' => true, 
                    'id' => 'unidad_id',
                    'empty' => 'Seleccione una unidad'
                ]); ?>
            </div>
```

Ajax:

```
//Cargar unidades al selector
$('#edificio_id').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("#edificio_id option:selected").text();

    var valueSelected = this.value;


    getUnidades(valueSelected);
});

function getUnidades(edificio_id){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: HOST + "/admin/Unidades/getUnidades",
        data:"idEdificio="+edificio_id,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#unidad_id option').remove();
            var optionUnidad = $("#unidad_id");

            if(data.length >= 1){
                $.each(data, function(i,items){
                    optionUnidad.append(new Option(items.descripcion,items.id));          
                }); 
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Algo ha fallado, intente nuevamente !");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:(lo único que hace es devolver las unidades pertenecientes al edificio)

```
public function getUnidades()
{
     $this->autoRender = false;      
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) { 
        $idEdificio = $this->request->data['idEdificio'];

        $unidades= $this->Unidades->find()
            ->select(['id','descripcion'])
            ->where(['Unidades.edificio_id' => $idEdificio ])
            ->order('Unidades.descripcion');

        // debug($unidades);exit;

        $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
        die(json_encode($unidades));     
    }
}
```

Comment: por lo que veo tienes una llamada a `getUnidades` con dos valores, pero en su declaración solo tienes uno, has mirado si en la consola te sale error?

Comment: Perdón ese segundo valor no va , está mal ahí lo corregí
Solo queda el primer valor
Igualmente eso no lo soluciona

Comment: Dentro de _success_ coloca `console.log(data);` ¿Qué obtienes?